# Как копировать текст в системный буфер обмена в vim?

Tags: vim, vimrc

У меня в vim не работает копирование и вставка из системного буфера, как это исправить?

```
$ vim --version

VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Oct 01 2021 01:51:08)
Included patches: 1-2434
Extra patches: 8.2.3402, 8.2.3403, 8.2.3409, 8.2.3428
Modified by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Compiled by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary
+arabic            +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+autochdir         +float             +mouse_xterm       -tcl
-autoservername    +folding           +multi_byte        +termguicolors
-balloon_eval      -footer            +multi_lang        +terminal
+balloon_eval_term +fork()            -mzscheme          +terminfo
-browse            +gettext           +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
++builtin_terms    -hangul_input      +num64             +textobjects
+byte_offset       +iconv             +packages          +textprop
+channel           +insert_expand     +path_extra        +timers
+cindent           +ipv6              -perl              +title
-clientserver      +job               +persistent_undo   -toolbar
-clipboard         +jumplist          +popupwin          +user_commands
+cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +vartabs
+cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +virtualedit
+comments          +libcall           -python            +visual
+conceal           +linebreak         -python3           +visualextra
+cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +viminfo
+cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +vreplace
+cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +wildignore
+cursorshape       -lua               -ruby              +wildmenu
+dialog_con        +menu              +scrollbind        +windows
+diff              +mksession         +signs             +writebackup
+digraphs          +modify_fname      +smartindent       -X11
-dnd               +mouse             -sound             -xfontset
-ebcdic            -mouseshape        +spell             -xim
+emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         +startuptime       -xpm
+eval              +mouse_gpm         +statusline        -xsmp
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
+extra_search      +mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Wdate-time -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/vim-DtwDbo/vim-8.2.2434=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 
Linking: gcc -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim -lm -ltinfo -lselinux -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl 




$ cat .vimrc 

call plug#begin()
Plug 'tpope/vim-sensible'
call plug#end()
```

EDIT: Как писал Stanislav Volodarskiy, у меня vim собран без опции `clipboard`. В интернете нашлась информация:

> поставь gvim (на арче) или vim-gtk (на дебиане)

Использую LMDE5 (x64), после установки vim-gtk заработало, но системный буфер не "*, а "+ . Буфер "* работает странно, в интернете написано, что они разные

Так же есть способ копирования в буфер с помощью выделения фрагмента текста в Visual Mode, после чего вводится команда:

```
:w !xclip -selected clipboard
```

Вставлять текст из буфера можно с помощью ctrl + shift + V

Comment: Скопируйте что-нибудь в системный буфер обмена. В Vim выполните `:reg`. Видите ли данные буфера обмена в одном из регистров?

Comment: Опция `-clipboard` означает что ваша копия Vim собрана без поддержки системного буфера обмена. :(. Ставьте другую версию.

Answer (score 0):

Как писал Stanislav Volodarskiy, у меня vim собран без опции `clipboard`. В интернете нашлась информация:

> поставь gvim (на арче) или vim-gtk (на дебиане)

Так же есть способ копирования в буфер с помощью выделения фрагмента текста в Visual Mode, после чего вводится команда:

```
:w !xclip -selected clipboard
```

Вставлять текст из буфера можно с помощью ctrl + shift + V